# How to encrypt/hide ClearText password in PowerShell Transcript

Tags: powershell, security, logging

I have used the `Start-Transcript` command in my PowerShell profile. This is very useful for me to review the console output of my scripts at a later point in time when required. However, at times I also directly run some commands that include a **ClearText password** like the `Set-ADAccountPassword` cmdlet. Now, these passwords also get captured in the Transcript log file which poses a security risk.

So, is there a way PowerShell can recognize these password related commands and hide them with `*`'s in the Transcript log file.

I do not see any parameter in the `Start-Transcript` that would enable this behavior. Is there a workaround?

EDIT:
The command used (with ClearText password) is like the below,

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity 'CN=Elisa Daugherty,OU=Accounts,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com' -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "p@ssw0rd" -Force)
```

Comment: Please add an example of how you use a **ClearText password** in that question as [`Set-ADAccountPassword `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adaccountpassword) only accepts **`[SecureString]`** types for a password...

Comment: See also: [Hide not the output but the actual command containing sensitive info in devops logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70068361/1701026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All passwords accepted by the [`Set-ADAccountPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adaccountpassword) cmdlet are encrypted (**`SecureString`**) passwords:

> ```
> Set-ADAccountPassword
>    [-WhatIf]
>    [-Confirm]
>    [-AuthType <ADAuthType>]
>    [-Credential <PSCredential>]
>    [-Identity] <ADAccount>
>    [-NewPassword <SecureString>]
>    [-OldPassword <SecureString>]
>    [-Partition <String>]
>    [-PassThru]
>    [-Reset]
>    [-Server <String>]
>    [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

Nevertheless, if you come across a cmdlet (or an external command) that accepts plain text passwords, ***that*** would be your security weakness to be resolved as that is not just captured by `Start-Transcript` but also sent to the host console and displayed.

Saying that, you should not hardcode passwords in your scripts as in the example of `Set-ADAccountPassword` :

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity elisada -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "p@ssw0rd" -Force) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "qwert@12345" -Force)
```

Instead, use the encrypted string as input for the [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-7).
To create the secure string, use the follwing sommand: (*don't hardcode this in your scripts either*):

```
Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

Results:

```
12345678d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000c8e74a7ee4e2da4eae03ae6fbc416934123456789200000000001066000000010000200000002568f3e73d018b1d0ee8a616c8aa2e9614bad0a6bb62ac76aa4b2b90c0178d4b000000000e80000000020000200000002e443228fdf8e2c54b356420d854535e9acc13dcf635755ae80d17bca4ec3cce20000000a4517f6ca8873e9431a5cd9af714617116014ede30e1a927c856ed4738e03a2340000000ce49ddafe4da3f8cd64e14c347126d5e8907fa16deb9f5133f8807b675f40a3354465868414aba785fcde64bbd98a125924ccfb16ad718f8f24698c3dab88c0d
```

And use the results in the concerned script (without the `-AsPlainText` switch), e.g.:

```
$OldPassword = '12345678d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000c8e74a7ee4e2da4eae03ae6fbc416934123456789200000000001066000000010000200000002568f3e73d018b1d0ee8a616c8aa2e9614bad0a6bb62ac76aa4b2b90c0178d4b000000000e80000000020000200000002e443228fdf8e2c54b356420d854535e9acc13dcf635755ae80d17bca4ec3cce20000000a4517f6ca8873e9431a5cd9af714617116014ede30e1a927c856ed4738e03a2340000000ce49ddafe4da3f8cd64e14c347126d5e8907fa16deb9f5133f8807b675f40a3354465868414aba785fcde64bbd98a125924ccfb16ad718f8f24698c3dab88c0d'
$NewPassword = '12345678d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000c8e74a7ee4e2da4eae03ae6fbc416934123456789200000000001066000000010000200000002568f3e73d018b1d0ee8a616c8aa2e9614bad0a6bb62ac76aa4b2b90c0178d4b000000000e80000000020000200000002e443228fdf8e2c54b356420d854535e9acc13dcf635755ae80d17bca4ec3cce20000000a4517f6ca8873e9431a5cd9af714617116014ede30e1a927c856ed4738e03a2340000000ce49ddafe4da3f8cd64e14c347126d5e8907fa16deb9f5133f8807b675f40a3354465868414aba785fcde64bbd98a125924ccfb16ad718f8f24698c3dab88c0d'
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity elisada -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $OldPassword) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $NewPassword)
```

***note 1*:** The encrypted string is only supposed to work under the account where it is created.

***note 2*:** quote from the [`SecureString Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netcore-3.1):

> We don't recommend that you use the SecureString class for new
> development. For more information, see [SecureString shouldn't be
> used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)
> on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you iRon, this is helpful. At times, I'm having to reset passwords in bulk. I usually generate some *random passwords* in a column in excel, use the `Set-ADAccountPassword` command as I stated in my question in a new column and then copy-paste the bunch of these commands from Excel to the PS console to reset the passwords. I then send out the credential note to the end-user and dispose the excel sheet used or replace the passwords with `*`s. The solution you provided ensures better security! I will implement this going forward.